# If I have stock that is unregistered at the time of a company buyout does my stock automatically register?

Tags: stocks, corporate-acquisition, rsu, compensation, sec

I was a contractor for a small public company for which I received stock compensation.  There is a fee to register the stock so I am waiting to see if the stock ends up being worth anything before paying the fee to have the legend removed and register the stock.  What happens to my stock in the event the company is acquired in an all cash deal before I register the stock?  Do I still have to register the stock or does it register automatically and the cash is deposited into my account?  Is there a difference if the acquisition is for stock in the new company instead of a cash buyout?

Comment: Where do you 'have' the stock? In your drawer (as paper), or at an broker, or where?

Comment: The actual cert is sitting in a broker account, I can see the stock when logging into my account but it is not registered and I cannot sell it.